# QuickText (Notepad++) plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, notepad++, code-completion

Is there a [QuickText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quicktext/) like (Tab Trigger) plugin for Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

If I read [Tab Triggers of TextMate](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles) correctly, especially the part stating:

> Tab triggers are also useful when they match program keywords and lead to actions (such as inserting snippets) that do what you would normally do after entering the keyword.

, the closest eclipse feature for that would be Preferences / Java / Editor / Templates
(the difference being that is is triggered *not* by <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but rather by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>...)

[image]

---

The [example for instance](http://www.iipt.fr/java.html) allows you to insert quite a bit of code after typing only three letters...

[image]
<sub>(source: [iipt.fr](http://www.iipt.fr/images/logging/0.png))</sub>

Comment: I know this feature but I was hoping there was something better...thanks anyway.

Comment: @Fraenek: I understand you, but I do not know of a strict equivalent of the Tab trigger with eclipse. That one ("templates") seems to be close enough.